# How to give a retro effect to an image in iPhopne app?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I have working on an app of iPhone. In this app user should be able to pick the app from Camera or Library. And after that he will be able to filter the images in various forms, like in Sepia tone, Cross processed and retro effect. How can an image be cross processed and how can it be given aretro effect through code in objective C?

Comment: @Vince : You should search the Google before voting down my question. Here is the image with retro effect. http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=retro+effect+images&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=7nd&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbm=isch&tbnid=MllBU-rIos46DM:&imgrefurl=http://photoscape-editor.blogspot.com/2011/03/tutorial-for-classic-retro-effect.html&docid=0hXMbpyvDmONtM&w=400&h=400&ei=C0ItTo6sK9GHrAe45_mxDQ&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=471&page=11&tbnh=166&tbnw=184&start=151&ndsp=13&ved=1t:429,r:12,s:151&tx=76&ty=115&biw=1152&bih=695

Comment: I didn't vote down your question, but you should provide more explanations on what you want exactly, or post the comment link in your question. I don't know if I'm really supposed to google to understand the question.

Comment: The link you provide is a Photoshop tutorial. It tells you the steps to go through to get these effects. Your real question is "How do I apply these steps to a UIImage?" What you expect us to do is to go to the other site, read the post and come back here and tell you how to do it. What have you tried?

Comment: @Abizern: I know that was a Photoshop Tutorial but my intention was to make you guys understand how image looks after giving it Retro effect. I hope it will be clear to you now. I was not asking you to give me the code. I was asking you if this possible in Objective C? Do you know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1. [Core Image framework present in iOS SDK.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html)
2. Manually doing your filtering by iterating over every pixel in the
   image. See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816295/iphone-how-to-convert-a-photo-into-a-pencil-drawing/5816646#5816646) question (not a direct answer to
   your question, but will link you to basic image filtering in
   iphone).