# How to give sketch effect on image in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing an iPhone application, in which I have implemented the following functionalities:

1. Select photo
2. Capture photo
3. Now I want to give a sketch effect to that photo like [this one.](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/photo-to-sketch/id421785759?mt=8)

How could I do this?

Comment: Do you get solution for your problem?

Answer (score 6):

If I may once again recommend it, my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework has a built in filter that does just this. The GPUImageSketchFilter uses Sobel edge detection to highlight edges in black on images or video, leading to the exact same effect as seen in that application:

[image: Sketch filter]

The above image was drawn from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9402041/19679), where I describe how that filter works, as well as show a couple other filter examples.

In fact, the SimplePhotoFilter example application that comes with the framework does exactly what you describe (capture a photo, apply a sketch filter to it, and save it to the photo library), so I'd start there if you want to get this up and running quickly.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV can be used  to give sketch effect on image in iphone.

Refer [iphone-how-to-convert-a-photo-into-a-pencil-drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816295/iphone-how-to-convert-a-photo-into-a-pencil-drawing) link and get helped.

Comment: found this website, with very close sketch - https://sketchmypic.com/

Answer (score 0):

Core Image filters are probably the best way to go.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/.

Comment: Unfortunately, that documentation was copied and pasted from the Mac documentation on Core Image and those filters aren't included in Core Image on iOS as of 5.1: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8528726/19679

Comment: Just checked, and yes you are correct, I copied them from the Apple wiget.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate that the documentation is a little out of sync with what's actually there on the device. I should probably file an enhancement request on that. The lack of these filters is one of the reasons I wrote the framework in my answer.