# How can i get a proper Sketching Photos?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to give sketch effect on image in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861313/how-to-give-sketch-effect-on-image-in-iphone)

[image]

Hi all,

I am a newbie.

I've tried solve to my problem. I'm Working on Photo Sketching Apps. But don't know how to get Proper Photo Sketching images. 
So how can I get a proper Pencil Sketching effect? Here are some example images.

Kindly guide me a way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper"?  What would be the difference between a proper and an improper sketching photo?

Comment: This is quite a big question. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com). What bits are you having problem with. Why has what you've done so far not worked?

Comment: @Rameshbhuja do you get solution to your problem?

Comment: @PayalManiyar yes..... this question asked in 2012 .... why ? any suggestions ?

Comment: I want to know solution. Can you help me?

Comment: @PayalManiyar i don't remember that things. But you can use GPUImage Library.....

Comment: okay. thanks. With the GPUImage I tried but not getting result as I want

Answer (score 1):

Core Image filters are probably the best way to go, CILineOverlay and CIEdgeWork when blended together could give the effect you are after. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/.

(From another answer of mine)