# How to use various effect or filters in iphone camera application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply “filters” to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156872/how-to-apply-filters-to-avcapturevideopreviewlayer)

Hello i want to use various effect and filters in my camera application  Effects include sepia, black and white,Anaglyph, swirl, neon light, rainbow, emboss, any tutorials ,example please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have to use AVFoundation, there is option that you can even change color of each pixel as per your requirement.

Comment: Have you searched it on SO ??? I think nope. see these links -

[How to apply “filters” to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156872/how-to-apply-filters-to-avcapturevideopreviewlayer) **AND**
[iPhone: How to convert a photo into a pencil drawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816295/iphone-how-to-convert-a-photo-into-a-pencil-drawing)

Comment: Here is [Example by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Listings/Classes_RosyWriterViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110-Classes_RosyWriterViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_10) In this example you can change pixel color for each buffer. Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Brad Larson's [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework provides a large number of GPU accelerated effects. Just integrate the GPUImage framework into your project and use the filters as you need. It's easy to implement.

Tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5689/beginning-core-image-in-ios-5

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **Core Image Filter Reference** there is option that you can even change color of each pixel..

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html

Hope this will help you...