# Camera App with Mltiple effects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, avfoundation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use various effect or filters in iphone camera application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813971/how-to-use-various-effect-or-filters-in-iphone-camera-application)

I want develop an application in which i can integrate multiple effect like the photo Booth Software (MAC default software) how can i create these camera app [image]

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question.

Answer (score 0):

As a start you can take a look at the excellent GPUImage framework from Brad Larson.
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

GPUImage comes with a lot of filters out of the box, but also provides a framework for writing your own ones.

Comment: olegam Thanks   for your Help if you have any other tutorials please send it to me