# How to add photo effect on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, photo, photography

How do I add effect (e.g. lomo) to a photo on iOS?

To make it simple, I wanna try to make an iPhone app which is similar to those photography apps, and I want a tutorial to start with.

Comment: If you're planning on writing an app that does image processing, wouldn't it be smart to first learn something *about* image processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As coreImage framework is not present in iphone (atleast upto iOS 4.0), you will have to do image filtering by hand..You have to iterate through each pixel in an image and work on it..[This](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11158-share-your-image-proccessing-filter-code.html) thread discussed about various image filtering effects in iphone and is very useful..[These](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14089) guys say they are successful in porting imageMagick to iOS but I never tried that..Also I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590216/polaroid-filter-from-uiimage) about implementing polaroid filter in iOS, though it didnt get a good answer, the question itself might be helpful..

Comment: Well, [Core Image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage?language=objc) was added on iOS 5.0.